# Flexnav Menu Buttons using only the width of their content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know, if it is possible to use flexnav without it's fixed width buttons.

It would be great if all nav - items only use the width they need to display their text + their padding. At the Moment I've to divide 100% with the number of nav items we have. This value is set with .flexnav li{}

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>Flexnav - Content Width Test</h1>
  <div class="menu-button">Show Menu</div>
  <div class="nav-container container">
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">
        <li><a href="">Startpage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Product Category 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Large Product Category</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Small one</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">PPPPProducts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>The red space is needed for a search and some Icons</p>
  </div>
```

I've made a codepen, so that you can see the working nav. I hope someone hopefully could give me a hint how to solve this problem:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aCjGq

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

'At the Moment I've to divide 100% with the number of nav items we have.'- **no need** to do that. Just give the container `div` of the menu a width and use the flexnav plugin in the following way :

```
$(".flexnav").flexNav({

             'calcItemWidths': true , // dynamically calcs top level nav item widths
       });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. calcItemWidths divides the width equally. The poster wants to assign the width as needed by the content.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but this might help someone. You can add this to the CSS:

```
  .flexnav > li {
    width: auto;
  }
  .flexnav > li.has-subitems {
    padding-right: 30px;/*to account for the menu dropdown icon*/
  }
  .flexnav li ul{
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    min-width: 210px;/*or whatever you want*/
  }
```